# Input type search with Accessibility compatibe?

Tags: html, accessibility

```
<input type="search" placeholder="search" />
```

The screen reader ignores this when search field is focused! What attribute to be added so that the screen reader would say "This is a search box " Thanks.

Comment: Maybe adding a `title` attr would help? Like `title="This is a search box"`

Comment: Why did you add the tag [tag:html5-canvas]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to make it accessible is use text and markup around the `input` element rather than attributes. This way, you don’t rely on any specific support to some special attributes (which greatly varies across browsers). Example:

```
<form action=... role="search">
<h2>Search this site</h2>
<label for="q">Keywords:</label>
<input type="search" id="q" name="q">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Then it is OK that the input field is spoken as a normal text field, since the user already knows it’s for entering keywords for a search.

If you are forced to play with small input box without a label, due to site layout requirements, then accessibility is inevitably reduced. You can try to help some users with some attributes that might get recognized and used by some browsers, e.g.

```
<input type="search" name="q" placeholder="keywords"
       title="Keywords for a site-wide search"
       aria-label="Keywords for a site-wide search">
```

Note: The [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-placeholder) should contain text that acts a hint of the expected input, rather than a general name for some functionality.

Reference for `role` and `aria-*` attributes: [Using WAI-ARIA in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/) (WD).